# Unable Connect To Internet In Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, ethernet

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on Dell Vostro 3446 and immediately updated Ubuntu. It asked me to restart and I did it. After the restart, I'm not able to connect to internet using ethernet adapter. **I have tried all sort of solutions listed on askubuntu.com and ubuntuforums.org and nothing worked.** Please help me with this.

Comment: show output of : `ifconfig` and `ip route`

Answer (score 0):

verify that your ethernet devices did not change names after the update/reboot. in your /etc/network/interfaces file you probably have something like:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Check dmesg output that the device is still being called ethX. I have seen them become emX. If they have changed, you need to make changes to /etc/network/interfaces to reflect the different device name.